# How create symmetric sparse matrix by SymSparseMat class of qpOASES？

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix

I have saw the hpp file to see how to create create symmetric sparse matrix by SymSparseMat class of qpOASES and there are five arguments need to be input:

> ```
>                   int_t nr,           /**< Number of rows. */
>                   int_t nc,           /**< Number of columns. */
>                   sparse_int_t* r,    /**< Row indices (length). */
>                   sparse_int_t* c,    /**< Indices to first entry of columns (nCols+1). */
>                   real_t* v           /**< Vector of entries (length). */
> ```

I don't know what the **3th to 5th** arguments mean. Could anyone please just give me a simple example(like 3*3 matrix) to explain what these 3 arguments stand for?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [qpOASES manual PDF](https://projects.coin-or.org/qpOASES/export/116/html/doc/3.1/manual.pdf) says "Sparse matrices are stored
in column compressed storage format." Aka CCS or CSC format. See the [explanation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_(CSC_or_CCS)) for what this means.

There is an example use in [examples/qrecipe.cpp](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/acado/html/qpOASES-3_82_80_2examples_2qrecipe_8cpp_source.html):

> ```
> /* create sparse matrices */
> SymSparseMat *H = new SymSparseMat(180, 180, H_ir, H_jc, H_val);
> SparseMatrix *A = new SparseMatrix(91, 180, A_ir, A_jc, A_val);
> ```

in which H_ir, H_jc, etc. are round-aboutly defined in [qrecipe_data.hpp](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/acado/html/qrecipe__data_8hpp.html).

Comment: HI，Mr Getreuer! So much thanks for your quick reply! Now I understand what these agruments mean.I have pressed useful button but the displayed post score is not changed because my low reputation

Comment: @BrPAl No worries, I'm glad that helped =)